# serve 404 page from a folder with static files when using Joomla

Tags: apache, joomla, http-status-code-404

I have a Joomla site running on Apache and Ubuntu 12.04. I wanted to show a custom 404 pages to be shown when a 404 error occure. I have made necessary changes to error.php file in my template directory to redirect it to '/404' directory where I have an index.html file with many images,css and java script.

Now when accessing a non-existent page, Joomla is redirecting me to root/404 but there I get a 403 Forbidden error from appache. The 404 directory is located inside 'htdocs' directory of Joomla installation.

Additional info:
1. I don't want to convert my 404 page into a Joomla template or article.
2. I am using a Joomla AMI from Bitnami on Amazon web service

Answer (score 0):

If you *redirect* to a 404 page, you corrupt the error mechanism. The client will never get that 404 status, but a 200 on successful redirect to your error page.

Instead, you should modify your template's error.php to

1. send the `404 Not Found` header
2. directly send the error page using [`readfile()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

You might have to adjust the asset paths within your error page.

Answer (score 0):

That's totally wrong, working with static pages does not mean that you have to overcome Joomla's routing.
You should either override the error Page view or use custom error pages.
Take a look at Joomla's documentation.http://docs.joomla.org/Custom_error_pages
Nibra was totally right about breaking the mechanism but still using a readfile() seems as an overkill.